# Resolutions of semi free (or almost free) commutative dg algebras with finitely generated cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, derived-algebraic-geometry, differential-graded-algebras

Let $A^{\bullet}:=\{ \cdots \rightarrow A^i \overset{d^i}{\rightarrow} A^{i+1} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow A^{-1} \rightarrow A^0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots \}$ be a non-positively graded commutative dg $k$-algebra, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.

We assume that $H^j(A^{\bullet})$ is a finitely generated $H^0(A)$-module for all $j$.
($A^j$ is not necessarily a finitely generated $A^0$-module.)

We call $A$ is a semi free when $A \simeq A^0 \otimes_{\mathbb{k}}\mathbb{k}[\{X_l \}_l]$ as $\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$-graded $A^0$-algebras, where $\{X_l\}_l$ is a set of variables with deg $(X_l)<0$ and $\mathbb{k}[\{X_l \}_l]$ is a freely generated commutative dg $k$-algebra.
(based on [Definition 1.3 on page 10 of "Rigid Complexes via DG Algebras"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603733v3), [Definition 1.5 on page 8 of "Differential Graded Schemes I: Perfect Resolving Algebras"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212225v1))

We also call $A$ is almost free if $A$ is freely generated (as a $\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$-graded $A^0$-algebra) by a sequence $P_j$ of finitely generated projective $A^0$-module, where each $P_j$ is contained in $A^{m(j)}$ for some $m(j)<0$.
(based on [Definition 2 on page 9 of "Shifted symplectic structures on derived Quot-stacks I: Differential graded manifolds"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03021))

**Question** :

If $A$ is semi free (resp. almost free), then can we get a dg $k$-subalgebra $B$ of $A$ such that $B$ is quasi-isomorphic to $A$, each $B^j$ is a finitely generated $B^0$-module and $B$ is semi free (resp. almost free) ?
If we need, assume $A^0$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

My original question is in [the last paragraph on page 15 of "Shifted symplectic structures on derived Quot-stacks II -- Derived Quot-schemes as dg manifolds"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.02815), that is, why does any dg-manifold $\tilde{X}=(X, \mathcal{O}^{\bullet}_X)$ of infinite type with finite cohomologies (i.e., each $H^i(\mathcal{O}^{\bullet}_X)$ is a coherent $H^0(\mathcal{O}^{\bullet}_X)$-module) have a sub dg-manifold $\tilde{Y}=(Y, \mathcal{O}^{\bullet}_Y)$ of finite type which is quasi-isomorphic to $\tilde{X}$ ?

It seems that it is well-known that any non-positively graded dga $A$ is quasi-isomorphic to a non-positively graded semi free dga $C$ such that $C^j$ is a finitely generated $C^0$-module under our assumption (i.e., $H^j(A)$ is a finitely generated $H^0(A)$-module for all $j$).
You can see this in [Proposition 1.7 on page 10 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603733v3).
It is not obvious to me whether we can choose $C$ as a dg subalgebra.

Moreover, semi free dgas correspond to dg Lie algebras via Chevalley-Eilenberg complexes. ([Section 2.2 on page 4 of "DG coalgebras as formal stacks"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9812034))
So, our discussion may be attributed to the discussion of dg Lie algebras.

**Edit**

I added some references and more explanation (2/26).
I also corrected mistakes.